# Include existing jquery functions on ajax loaded elements Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have some functions at the end of my HTML which use jquery to do some stuff

```
function transformacija() {
    if ($("#drugiPrviPage").hasClass("pocetna")) {
        $("#drugiPrviPage").velocity({
                left: "-100%",
                opacity: 0.3
            },
            "slow"
        )
        $("#drugiPodPage").velocity({
                right: "10%",
                opacity: 1
            },
            "slow"
        )
    } else {
        $("#drugiPrviPage").velocity({
                left: "10%",
                opacity: 1
            },
            "slow"
        )
        $("#drugiPodPage").velocity({
                right: "-100%",
                opacity: 0.3
            },
            "slow"
        )
        $("#prviPage").removeClass("pocetna");
        $("#drugiPodPage").empty();

    }

}



$(".prvilinkovi").click(function() {
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    var idt = id + '.txt';
    $(document).ajax({
        url: [idt],
        type: "GET",
        cache: false,
        success: function(txt) {
            $("#drugiPodPage").html(txt);

        }
    });
    transformacija();

});
}
```

Basicly when i click the button with class "prvilinkovi" i'm loading content into a div with ajax and then i have the same button on the ajax loaded div and i want it to have the same function as button that initialy clicked. I added class "pocetna" to the ajaxloaded button but it doesn't have the functions like the first button.

How could i delegate the functions to work on the ajax loaded content?

I've tried puting the code into an init function and call it on ajaxcomplete event but it doesn't seem to work at all then (even though i used on document.ready() to call the init function aswell.

I went for this method of ajax loading to dinamicly load page parts when clicked upon a category with a cool velocity animation to have the onepage model for the website and when u go back it empties the div and is ready for the next category click.

Comment: You need event delegation here to attach events to dynamically loaded stuffs. But its quite unclear looking on to your question as in what you need exactly. Could you please give an example? or show how DOM elements look after ajax load?

Comment: http://medo.studio4host.hr/interma is the thing i'm doing. When on the grey part u click AAAA button it loads the content from .txt file to the other div and animates it to get into place, the AAAA button on the yellow page doesn't have the same functionality as the first AAAA button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. As per my understanding, you can do it as below:

- Keep a common class, say `pocetna` to both divs - `drugiPodPage` and `drugiPrviPage`.
- Attach click event to `document` or any closest element which is present on `DOM load`. Since `pocetna` class will be present during `document.ready` we will attach the event to it, delegating to its button as below:

**JS**

```
$('.pocetna').on('click',".prvilinkovi",function() {
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    var parentID=$(this).closest('.pocetna').attr('id'); //get the button's parent id
    if(parentID=="drugiPrviPage") //if its previous page perform ajax call
    {
         var idt = id + '.txt';
         $(document).ajax({
              url: [idt],
              type: "GET",
              cache: false,
              success: function(txt) {
                   $("#drugiPodPage").html(txt);
                   //move the divs only on success
                   $("#drugiPrviPage").velocity({
                        left: "-100%",
                        opacity: 0.3
                   },"slow");
                   $("#drugiPodPage").velocity({
                        right: "10%",
                        opacity: 1
                   },"slow");
               }
          });
    }
    else
    {
         $("#drugiPrviPage").velocity(
         {
               left: "10%",
               opacity: 1
         },"slow");
         $("#drugiPodPage").velocity(
         {
               right: "-100%",
               opacity: 0.3
         },"slow");
         $("#drugiPodPage").empty();
    }
});
```

Comment: Hey, I've noticed you have suggested a better solution for selecting which div which is really helpful for me didn't know you could do this. Now only the original problem persists. The button on the yellow page ( button is loaded with ajax as my .txt file contains <button class="prvilinkovi" id="bezbutton2">AAAA</button> for that button and when i click it the function doesn't trigger. I guess that i due that the functions are not initilized on the newly loaded button.

Comment: The newly created button with ajax is the same class as the initial button but the selector $(".prvilinkovi") doesn't work. Is there a way to reload the javascript when ajax is complete. I guess that would solve the problem.

Comment: My question is so unclear. I'm gonna try to refraise it.

Comment: Didn't really understand your solution until going through it a few times. Thank you for your answer it completly sovles the problem.

Comment: Sorry.. I was away from my system... Glad that you figured it out.. Happy coding.. :)